# Для картинки недостаточно памяти при использовании Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox

Код очень прост: Нажимаю на кнопку, в PictureBox загружается картинка.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FullName))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream).Clone();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Но когда из другой функции\события использую Graphics на pictureBox'е, то он ругается на то, что недостаточно памяти. Ругается на Graphics.FromImage не зависимо от того, что я буду с этим графиксом делать. Пример:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Вопрос-то в том, почему до загрузки картинки в PictureBox могу делать с Graphics чего душа пожелает:обрезать, заливать,рисовать; а после загрузки картинки нет?
p.s. Картинки пробовал разные и разного размера. Одна и та же картинка работает до загрузки(она уже была в pictureBox по умолчанию) и не работает после загрузки в pictureBox. 
Обошел достаточно много форумов по этой теме, но свой случай(или максимально похожий случай) не нашел.

Comment: Использовать invoke при обращении к pictureBox?

Comment: Invalidate() убрал, все равно System.OutOfMemoryException

Comment: System.OutOfMemoryException может возникать если вы пытаетесь что-то сделать за границами изображения. Например, нарисовать прямоугольник по координатам, которые находятся в "космосе"

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код некорректен: согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.7.2), поток, скормленный Image.FromStream, должен оставаться открытым на протяжении всего времени существования изображения. Кроме того, Bitmap.Clone на самом деле не делает то, что вы ожидаете (создание копии Bitmap, полностью независимой от исходного файла изображения).

Возможно, ваш код заточен под .NET 2.0, так как он в нем работает хотя бы частично (не бросает исключение, но все равно оставляет Bitmap зависимым от исходного файла, так что попытка сохранить его в другой файл после удаления исходного файла выдает "В GDI+ произошла ошибка общего вида"). Подробнее о различиях PictureBox в разных версиях .NET можете посмотреть [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/fb49b570-5319-4080-aa9e-bf66d38f724e/-gdi-?forum=msdnfeedbackru).

Правильный код для создания Bitmap, независимого от исходного файла изображения:

```
MemoryStream ms;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FullName = "...";
    ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FullName))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    }
}        


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }     
}
```